# Avoid overwriting into a cell

Tags: excel, vba, range, file-monitoring

I have created this code to monitor a folder in case of creation and deletion events.
However, the code I created overwrites always the same cell, whereas I would like to keep track of the changes. Hence I would like all the creation events to be listed in column A and the deletion events to be listed in column B.
Can somebody help me?

```
Select Case objEventObject.Path_.Class
       Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
       MsgBox "A new file was just created: " & objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
       Workbooks("MonitorDirectory").Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A2") = objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
        Exit Do
       Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent"
        MsgBox "A file was just deleted: " & objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
        Workbooks("MonitorDirectory").Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
        Exit Do
End Select
```

Comment: insert a new row before setting values for A2 and B2

Answer (score 1):

adding two variables x,y as below might work

```
   Select Case objEventObject.Path_.Class
Dim i As Integer
x = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
y = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

       Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
       MsgBox "A new file was just created: " & objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
       Workbooks("MonitorDirectory").Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & x) = objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
        Exit Do
       Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent"
        MsgBox "A file was just deleted: " & objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
        Workbooks("MonitorDirectory").Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B" & y).Offset(1, 0) = objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent
        Exit Do
End Select
```